# declaring a string to be passed into a sql query

Tags: sql

I have a list of strings that i would like to pass multiple times in a SQL query.

I would like to declare them once and then pass the list into the queries.  is this possible?

values:

```
'1-PGB4Z', '1-PGAT6', '1-PGB55', '1-PGB52',
'1-2SS1E6', '1-2SS1E3', '1-2RZQMZ', '1-2RZQNF', '1-2RZQMT', '1-2SACTZ', 
'1-2S0GNR', '1-2S0GLP', '1-2S0GCN', '1-1VOMUX', '1-1VOMV0', '1-1VOMV3', 
'1-1VOX7Z', '1-1VOX82', '1-1VOMV7', '1-1VOMVA', '1-1VOMVD', '1-1VOMVG', 
'1-1VPMBV', '1-1VPMBY', '1-1VPMC4', '1-1VO9XD', '1-1VO9XG', '1-1VO9XJ', 
'1-1VPMBY', '1-1VO9XJ', '1-1VO9XM', '1-1VO9Z6', '1-16PGRE', 
'1-16PGRK', '1-16PGRH', '1-8MNWB',  '1-9JAVH',  '1-8ISTX', '1-N5KYK', 
'1-KZMMH', '1-D7KG9', '1-9HCNP', '1-9H81K', '1-1C9F1P', '1-QBQQW',
'1-2S0F1P', '1-2S0F45', '1-2S17LK', '1-2S17LT', '1-2SL5D9', '1-2SDUQD'
```

part of query:

```
select * from table1 t3
where
 and t1.cse_id in 
(select d.cse_id 
from table1 d
where d.cse_employee_number in
(select substr(t2.emp_s3_id, 3,8) from table2 t2, table 3 T1 
where t2.fk_resource_group_id = t1.resource_group_id
and t1.resource_group_id in (
'1-PGB4Z', '1-PGAT6', '1-PGB55', '1-PGB52',
'1-2SS1E6', '1-2SS1E3', '1-2RZQMZ', '1-2RZQNF', '1-2RZQMT', '1-2SACTZ', 
'1-2S0GNR', '1-2S0GLP', '1-2S0GCN', '1-1VOMUX', '1-1VOMV0', '1-1VOMV3', 
'1-1VOX7Z', '1-1VOX82', '1-1VOMV7', '1-1VOMVA', '1-1VOMVD', '1-1VOMVG', 
'1-1VPMBV', '1-1VPMBY', '1-1VPMC4', '1-1VO9XD', '1-1VO9XG', '1-1VO9XJ', 
'1-1VPMBY', '1-1VO9XJ', '1-1VO9XM', '1-1VO9Z6', '1-16PGRE', 
'1-16PGRK', '1-16PGRH', '1-8MNWB',  '1-9JAVH',  '1-8ISTX', '1-N5KYK', 
'1-KZMMH', '1-D7KG9', '1-9HCNP', '1-9H81K', '1-1C9F1P', '1-QBQQW',
'1-2S0F1P', '1-2S0F45', '1-2S17LK', '1-2S17LT', '1-2SL5D9', '1-2SDUQD', 
'1-2SDUTD', '1-2FRRMN', '1-2GHUNX', '1-2FXDD6', '1-2FWFG1', '1-2FR8CR', 
'1-2FWFLM', '1-2FH7YL', '1-2FRRMX', '1-2GDIE3', '1-2FWFQI', '1-2FWFNL', 
'1-2U9ULR', '1-2U4ZZP', '1-2SC2WF', '1-2SXPKJ', '1-2TDSJ5')
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be better to store these values in a 'lookup' table and use this as the criteria within your query. If the values then changes, you do not have to go through the hassle of updating any stored procedures that use them.

For example

```
select * from table1 t3
where
 and t1.cse_id in 
(select d.cse_id 
from table1 d
where d.cse_employee_number in
(select substr(t2.emp_s3_id, 3,8) from table2 t2, table 3 T1 
where t2.fk_resource_group_id = t1.resource_group_id
and t1.resource_group_id in (SELECT value from lookup table)
```

As far as I am aware, there is no way to directly create a variable that is an array, but you can create a variable of VARCHAR that can be used with other functions to simulate searching an array. However this will not work directly within an `IN` statement

Comment: +1 - For SQL Server he could do a table variable in the body of the proc as well if he liked.

Comment: in SQL Server you can do a table variable, basically `DECLARE @TableVar TABLE(Field1, Field2)` then insert into it like a normal table.

Comment: @JNK True, but if you are using this within multiple SPs and you need to change the values then a lookup table is probably the better choice. Valid point though and something to consider if if is only used in a single place.

Answer (score 0):

if this are "permanent" values, fill a table with them and join it

Answer (score 0):

It is NOT possible to define comma separated values and to use them as IN() statement (will not work). 
Temp table is the only solution.

Answer (score 0):

way 1:
ChrisBint is right. instead (val1,val2,val3) you can use (SELECT val FROM vals_tbl), and store the vals in vals_tbl.
It is the better way.

way 2:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE exe_str(command TINYTEXT)/*exec the string*/
BEGIN
    PREPARE stmt1 FROM command;
    EXECUTE stmt1;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;
END
```

Now, you can create string of the SELECT statement, and execute it :

```
SET @str1="SELECT .........";
SET @str2="'1-PGB4Z', '1-PGAT6'........";
SET @str3=");";
CALL exe_str(CONCAT(@str1,@str2,str3));
```

I recommends the first way.